# Recursive meta

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What about meta-meta stackoverflow.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55/what-about-meta-meta-stackoverflow)

Is it also appropriate to use http://meta.stackoverflow.com to discuss Meta Stack Overflow itself?

Comment: Duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55/what-about-meta-meta-stackoverflow

Answer (score 3):

Time to re-read "Gödel, Escher, Bach".

Answer (score 1):

I think we need meta.meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: Wow, this could get ugly fast.

Comment: so where would you discuss meta-meta-SO? ;-)

Comment: A capital idea! And, when we wish to discuss the the complement of subjects covered by meta.meta.stackoverflow, we would simply go to moc.wolfrevokcats.atem.atem.

Comment: Additionally, am I the only one slightly freaked out by the fact that it never occured to me that ```echo 'stackoverflow' | rev``` yields the words ```wolf```, ```cats```, and something a Levenshtein distance of 1 away from ```revoke```? In any case, no one tell Dan Brown. I don't want to have to deal with the consequences.