# According to meta's faq, this question wouldn't be allowed

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What about meta-meta stackoverflow.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55/what-about-meta-meta-stackoverflow)

I just read the FAQ again (don't ask me why), and it says:

> If your question is about:
>
> Stack Overflow
>   Server Fault
>   Super User
>   ... it is welcome here.

It doesn't say I may post questions about Meta, like this one. Or is it really illegal to post Meta questions on Meta? There is even a `meta-so` tag.

Comment: Belongs on meta.meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: Which doesn't exist -_-

Comment: Divide by zerio? Oh shiiiii....

Comment: Some readings: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10077/meta-so-meta-meta-meta - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55/what-about-meta-meta-stackoverflow

Comment: Obviously, questions on meta.meta.stackoverflow.com belong on meta.meta.meta.stackoverflow.com.  However, where do we ask questions about that infinite regress?

Comment: It's metas all the way down.