# What name would you suggest instead of Meta Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, meta

I've been using Meta Stack Overflow for about a month or two now.

- What name you would suggest instead of Meta in Meta Stack Overflow?

  - And why would that name suit?

Comment: Tell us why Meta doesn't suit.

Comment: @random i never had a problem with the name "meta".. I ve asked for other names

Comment: Almost anything but support.stackoverflow.com

Comment: This would be a mete-meta question (a rather silly one as well).

Answer (score 7):

I would choose **http://meta.stackoverflow.com**.

Or maybe just **meta**.

The reason it is called meta is because it is a Q and A site about a Q and A site.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta):

> Meta- (from Greek: μετά = "after", "beyond", "with", "adjacent", "self"), is a prefix used in English (and other Greek-owing languages) to indicate a concept which is an abstraction from another concept, used to complete or add to the latter.

I feel meta is a very appropriate name.

Comment: +1 Creative, I like that. Maybe you should run for SO moderator.

Comment: Ha, maybe I should...*feels strange sense of Deja Vu*

Answer (score 2):

My problem isn't with meta, but with the stackoverflow.com part.

Maybe meta.sofu.com or something? (Unfortunately it seems that every single non-localised version of `sofu` is taken - .com .net .org .info)

I know I know I know, stackoverflow is the name of the engine, and the company, but that doesn't change my opinion that the usage of stackoverflow.com in the meta domain just feels exclusive, rather than inclusive.

Comment: "sofu" either sounds like a curse word or soybean curd.  can't decide which is worse.

Comment: SOUF would be worse. @notevengoingtotryandguesstheminimumonthatname

Comment: meta.superuser.com and meta.serverfault.com should at least redirect to here, rather than 404-ing, and with such an ugly 404 message to boot!

Comment: @Æther - they now do (well, meta.serverfault.com does anyway)! Yippee

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking why the word "meta" is significant?

> Meta- (from Greek: μετά = "after", "beyond", "with", "adjacent", "self"), is a prefix used in English (and other Greek-owing languages) to indicate a concept which is an abstraction from another concept, used to complete or add to the latter.
>
> In epistemology, the prefix meta is used to mean about (its own category). For example, metadata are data about data (who has produced them, when, what format the data are in and so on)...
>
> Douglas Hofstadter, in his 1979 book [Gödel, Escher, Bach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38210/what-non-programming-books-should-programmers-read/40166#40166) (and in the sequel, Metamagical Themas), popularized this meaning of the term. This book, which deals extensively with self-reference and touches on Quine and his work, was influential in many computer-related subcultures, and is probably largely responsible for the popularity of the prefix, for its use as a solo term, and for the many recent coinages which use it. Hofstadter uses the meta as a stand-alone word, both as an adjective and as a directional preposition ("going meta", a term he coins for the old rhetorical trick of taking a debate or analysis to another level of abstraction, as in "This debate isn't going anywhere."). This book is also probably responsible for the direct association of "meta" with self-reference, as opposed to just abstraction. The sentence "This sentence contains thirty-six letters," and the sentence it is embedded in, are examples of sentences that reference themselves in this way.

Source: [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta)

See also: [meta-meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55/what-about-meta-meta-stackoverflow)

Comment: Woah, poaching my Wikipedia answer...Shame!!!

Comment: I think our submissions crossed in midair... was searching for good 'meta' references.

Comment: I'll allow it...but just this time.  You get three warnings...consider this your first two. `:)`

Comment: The Google `define: meta` looks like enough of a mess of a reference.