# Is Meta Stack Overflow just the meta for Stack Overflow or is it a somewhat special meta site?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, meta

Initially I thought that Meta Stack Overflow was the common meta for all SE sites.

Then I noted that [English Language and Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/faq) has its own meta site.

It took a while for me to learn that even Server Fault has its own meta site.

Looking at my reputation points, I see difference between Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Overflow, but not between the other sites and there corresponding meta sites.

Now, is Meta Stack Overflow in some sense the master meta site of all or not?

Comment: Why isn't there a meta.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: @DanDascalescu there is now: https://meta.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See the blog post [New Per-Site Metas](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/new-per-site-metas/):

> **Meta Stack Overflow will serve as the “National Capital” where we process feedback not just for Stack Overflow but for the core engine itself** — while the smaller meta sites are akin to regional or state capitals. So, in a nutshell:

> - meta.stackoverflow.com is Washington, DC

- meta.serverfault.com is Columbus, OH
- meta.superuser.com is Sacramento, CA

> … and so forth.

Comment: excellent answer/analogy! +1

Comment: Thanks the answer is clear and the link is very usefull. BTW I'm very sure there was a third answer, which got deleted. But when even studiohack upvotes this answer I'll choose it

Comment: @bernd_k: jjnguy's answer was about meta.stackoverflow.com as opposed to meta.stackexchange.com (which is/was the meta site for Stack Exchange 1.0 sites).

Comment: Myers Thanks. I didn't yet find out how I can view the different revions of an question.

Comment: @bernd_k: You can't view deleted posts (other than your own) until you have 10k reputation. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that-actually-mean.

Answer (score 3):

Meta Stack Overflow is in a sense, the "master meta site" of them all, but if the issue just pertains to a particular site, ask it on the site's meta (e.g. Super User question goes on Super User's meta).

If the issue pertains to Stack Overflow, then it is asked on here, because *Meta Stack Overflow performs a **double duty** as meta for Stack Overflow, and the master site of them all".*