# New SO moderators are not Meta moderators (yet?)

Tags: discussion, status-completed, election, moderators

The [Meta *About* page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/about) states:

> Any community moderator from Stack Overflow is also a moderator here.

At time of writing (which is the morning after the election concluded), the three newly-elected moderators [George Stocker](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/16587/george-stocker), [Brad Larson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19679/brad-larson) and [ThiefMaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/298479/thiefmaster) have received their shiny new diamonds on Stack Overflow, but don't appear to have moderator status on Meta Stack Overflow.

- All three have diamonds in their SO profiles (links: [George](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16587/george-stocker), [Brad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19679/brad-larson), [ThiefMaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/298479/thiefmaster)) and are named as moderators on the [SO "About" page](https://stackoverflow.com/about)
- None of the three have diamonds in their Meta profiles (links: [George](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/16587/george-stocker); [Brad](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/135615/brad-larson); [ThiefMaster](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/147015/thiefmaster)) or are named as moderators on the [MSO "About" page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/about)

(N.B. I'm not just talking about their Flair images, which I know are cached. They don't seem to have actual moderator status on MSO.)

**Is this intentional (and SO moderators are *not* now always MSO mods); a defect; or am I just being impatient and the change is coming?**

Comment: Maybe they signed up on condition that they be spared from having to be Meta moderators. :)

Comment: `am I just being impatient and the change is coming?` This. Part of the process is manual, they'll get their MSO diamonds soon enough.

Comment: They just got their MSO diamonds.

Comment: @Yannis Thanks - I've updated BoltClock's answer accordingly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Basically what [Yannis Rizos](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/162704/yannis-rizos) said in his comment:

> Part of the process is manual, they'll get their MSO diamonds soon enough.

[Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) is currently a separate Stack Exchange site from [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com), and they're not exactly linked in the same way as other Stack Exchange sites (like the other trilogy sites, or the other SE 2.0 sites) are linked to their per-site metas.<sup>♦</sup>

As such, users who are promoted to moderators on SO won't automatically have diamonds on MSO; they have to be manually appointed in order to receive their meta-diamonds here. And that will come in a bit.

<sup>♦</sup> <sub>This is partly because MSO was originally intended to be [both SO's meta as well as the master meta for the whole network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73129/is-meta-stack-overflow-just-the-meta-for-stack-overflow-or-is-it-a-somewhat-spec). However, [this will change hopefully soon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124015/the-future-of-meta-stackoverflow-and-meta-stackexchange).</sub>

---

As [Yannis](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/162704/yannis-rizos) has pointed out in comments, they've now received their MSO diamonds, approximately a day after the election ended.

Comment: "active 3 months ago" :(

Comment: @AakashM: Yeah... it's more complicated than it looks :(

Comment: Anna Lear and I were bugging Shog in the chat. ;)