# Does a user become a Meta moderator by default the moment when he or she becomes a mod for SO?

Tags: discussion, election, moderators

I just saw 2014 SO election was ending with fire crackers. Two out of 3 mods were extremely familiar faces in SO. I noticed now both of them have SO as well as Meta `diamonds`...the moderator status.

Does it mean, when one is elected as a mod for SO, that person becomes a Meta mod by default?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the [Meta *About* page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/about) says:

> Any community moderator from Stack Overflow is also a moderator here.

However, the process is not automatic, AFAIK. As Yannis mentions in a [comment on related question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136866/new-so-moderators-are-not-meta-moderators-yet?rq=1#comment382709_136866), a part of this process is manual and diamonds are awarded manually.

The reason for this is mentioned in the answer by BoltClock's a Unicorn (on the same question):

> Meta Stack Overflow is currently a separate Stack Exchange site from Stack Overflow, and they're not exactly linked in the same way as other Stack Exchange sites (like the other trilogy sites, or the other SE 2.0 sites) are linked to their per-site metas.
>
> As such, users who are promoted to moderators on SO won't automatically have diamonds on MSO; they have to be manually appointed in order to receive their meta-diamonds here. And that will come in a bit.

Comment: Meta About page, that part is helpful

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Elected mods for a site are made mods on the corresponding meta site.

Comment: But this meta is not yet Stack Overflow child meta so it's not relevant. It's true for all other sites, just not Stack Overflow and this very meta site. In here it's not automatic, the SE employee who is assigning the moderators need to do it in both sites. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yet it shows up as a meta site on the site drop down, so there is clearly *some* indication to the system that this is the meta site of SO.

Comment: Of course there is, but the parent-meta relation here is unique and not automatic.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yes it's unique, and in some ways it's automatic and in some it's not.  I suppose at the end of the day though it's not really relevant to us whether the system does it or a person does; the point remains that mods on SO, just like every other site, are made mods on the corresponding meta site.  I removed the word "automatically" because it's simply irrelevant.

Comment: Yes, Stack Overflow moderators are automatically made moderators on Meta.SO. However, they do have to agree to a separate moderator agreement here (for access to private information, etc.), which some don't realize for a little while because of the low volume of stuff that needs to be moderated here.

Comment: Agreed. And soon we'll have Meta Stack Exchange born, so the big question is who will moderate it.

Comment: @ShadowWizard The community managers will moderate it.  Pretty sure that was in the announcement.  They said they might investigate other options if they can't handle the load, but they don't expect that to be the case.

Comment: @Servy oh, I think they will need extra hands. We'll see... :)

Comment: Some day, SO will have a proper child meta site and this will all be automatic, @Sha. For now, I just do it manually because MSO is both MSO and MSE. Not worried about who will moderate the eventual MSE at this time, since there are a couple dozen of us working here who are perfectly capable of handling things that are strictly "network-wide".

Comment: @BradLarson: You mean "not automatic"?

Comment: @AmalMurali - Sorry, meant that there wasn't a secondary election or any sort of internal debate over who was made a moderator of Meta.SO. SO moderators are all appointed to the position after election.

Comment: @ShadowWizard just to clarify and confirm. Conclusion is `1.` becoming a SO mod doesn't _necessarily_ make one a Meta mod. `2.` Another question, does new SO mod have the choice to become or not to become a Meta mod? or Meta mod is an `obligation` on top of SO mod? `3.` Can existing mods choose not to make SO mod a Meta mod?

Comment: @bonCodigo 1) yes it does, but the process is not automatic like on other sites. 2) I guess mod can, in theory, ask not to moderate this meta site, but as far as I know it never happened. 3) Existing moderators have no such power, it's not their decision to make. They can contact the team of course.

Comment: @ShadowWizard appreciate all info and enlightenment - some of these info aren't in about page anyway ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard very important question: can moderators still answer SO questions?

Comment: @bonCodigo of course they can, they're still users like you and me. It's their own time so if they give 1-2 hours for moderation things they're free to do whatever they want in the rest of their time.