# Where to ask questions about meta stack overflow?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What about meta-meta stackoverflow.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55/what-about-meta-meta-stackoverflow)

In my understanding, questions about Stack Overflow should be asked on Meta Stack Overflow. So where should questions (such as this one) about meta stack overflow be asked? Is there a meta meta stack overflow?

Comment: It's metas all the way down.

Comment: What happens when we need to ask questions about the place to ask questions about the place to ask questions about StackOverflow?  How long before we have a recursion reference?  An Inception reference?

Comment: @Charles: In that case you ask it on The Sex Channel here on chat.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Sergio, that is the perfect non-sequitur.

Comment: Can we have the meta-meta-discusstion tag?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We never meta question we didn't like.

Comment: I don't get it?

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a meta meta stack overflow?

nope. Just ask 'em here.