# Why does the "Post Locked" explanation suggest visiting Meta... on Meta?

Tags: discussion, locked-questions

The "Post Locked" banner suggests visiting Meta to get more info... even if the post in question is on Meta.

Shouldn't it link to the FAQ instead? Granted, the FAQ does not contain any info on this matter yet. Or should the link be removed completely? After all, the explanation is pretty explanatory. Removing the link would also stop people from coming here asking "Why was my question locked?"

**Edit:** Yeah, I know... nobody asks that.

[image: locked by Tim Post♦️ 1 min ago: This post has been locked while disputes about its content are being resolved. For more info visit meta.]

Comment: Dunno, I like the recursiveness of it all :)

Comment: So? If you want more info, just visit meta. I don't see what's wrong.

Comment: Related: [What about Meta meta?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55/what-about-meta-meta-stack-overflow)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is no longer the case, 11 and a half years later. The post notice looks like this now:

[image: Locked for 59 minutes. There are disputes about this answer's content being resolved at this time. It is not currently accepting new interactions.]

The link on "disputes about this answer's content" goes to [the help center article on locked posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/locked-posts), and no longer recursively links to Meta.