# More info on "For more info visit Meta" required

Tags: discussion, feature-request, hyperlinks, locked, wording

The current wording for content dispute notices is:

> This post has been locked while disputes about its content are being
> resolved. **For more info [visit meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com)**.

To me, the emphasised part isn't especially useful, since the page it takes me to has no relevant information. To a new user (especially one that hasn't been on Meta before), this might be outright confusing. It can get pretty silly, [since even locked posts on Meta tell you to go to Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113487/why-does-the-post-locked-explanation-suggest-visiting-meta-on-meta).

What say we take one of the following measures:

- Remove the text *"For more info visit meta"*, since it doesn't tell you anything useful
- If what is meant here is that the user should visit Meta to *discuss* the closing, this should be explicitly stated:

  > To discuss this, [please ask a question on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).
- Create a page where a detailed explanation is provided for what a content dispute is, and what the user is expected to do about it on Meta. Link to that in the notice. Should they ask a question, go to chat, read existing questions? Admittedly, I'm not too clear on this myself.

Comment: I've found this behavior odd in the past.  A direct link to a meta question where the post is under discussion (if one exists) would be useful

Comment: Yeah, this bugs me every time I see it. For 99% of all content disputes we don't have a meta post. Either you link it to a FAQ about what a content dispute is (no idea if we have that), encourage the reader to ask a question themselves, or just leave it out.

Comment: Wikipedia gets this right, the banners actually link to the discussion.