# How can I know the rules if people are always arguing here?

Tags: discussion, meta

I'm hanging around and find there is a lot of quarrel here, people debate different views about Stack Overflow, or if my question here is proper and so on. This kind of debate people have here confuse new users like myself, who are looking for guidance and clear rules.how to choose the answers for a newbie if there is a big difference in them?

Comment: With some difficulty...

Comment: @dmckee people say：follow your heart~

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I said in the comments, this [has been discussed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55/what-about-meta-meta-stack-overflow). The main reason for not having another meta site to discuss this meta site (so, a meta-meta site) is that then we would need another meta layer to discuss *that* site, a meta-meta-meta site. And that would go on forever...

If you, as a new user, are confused about what is the "right" way to behave on Stack Overflow or Meta, I understand your frustration. The problem is, many times there is no "right" way, people just think differently, and can disagree about pretty much everything. You get used to it after participating on Meta for a while, but until then... well, don't expect a final answer on everything, listen to the different opinions, and stick to the one *you* agree the most with. Also, try looking at questions tagged [faq](/questions/tagged/faq), their content tends to be more consensual (questions only get tagged faq after some discussion).

Comment: it's very interesting but you mis my idea,

Comment: @Winnie I hope the new paragraph I just added is more helpful.

Comment: yes thanks for your answer ,so the answer is ,when you don't know which is right,go with your heart,am I right?

Comment: @Winnie sort of. Heart *and* brains. Make an informed decision, but *your* decision.

Comment: maybe use brain sometime.:).why my question Duplicate:
What about meta-meta Stack Overflow,I can't find the same part,are their same?

Comment: @Winnie You question looked like a feature-request for a Meta-Meta, so they closed it. I edited the question trying to make (what I believe is) your point more clear, let's see if it gets reopened. Please edit further if you think you can make it more clear too.

Comment: oh ,thanks ,I think I should delete the "meta meta" words ,that isn't the main matter but cause lots of misunderstanding.

Answer (score 3):

Meta is the right place to discuss meta things about Meta.  Questions about Meta on meta can be tagged [meta](/questions/tagged/meta).

See also [meta-meta-meta](/questions/tagged/meta-meta-meta).

See also [semantic satiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_satiation).

Comment: and what I ask in here still has not a very clear answer.people who answered debate themself ,then how should a newuser choose?

Comment: New users that do not understand what's going on should be encouraged to read more and ask carefully crafted questions to help them understand if reading didn't help.  It sounds like you're asking about a specific incident.  Perhaps you should be asking about that incident instead of being so general about it.

Comment: like my question shoule I cover a old question with a new question by edit it ,there says you can delete it if you really care a bout the rep here ,but another says not to delete a question as stock-in-trade.I feel this is a discuss

Comment: (define (meta) (meta))???

Comment: @TinaCGHoehr no ,meta-beta just one of my imagine.my point is how to choose the different answers if the answer has argue with each other

Answer (score 2):

If the quarrels are polite but energetic then you couldn't really ask for more, unless nobody actually answers your question.  If the quarreling turns rude and personal then flag the comments as being inappropriate.