# How am I supposed to earn Constantinopolitan for Meta Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, meta, winter-bash-2012

So, as far as I can tell, I earned the Constantinopolitan hat for StackOverflow because I posted in Meta StackOverflow.  But now I want to earn it for Meta StackOverflow.  Is there some secret Meta Meta StackOverflow that I can post on to get the hat?

Comment: post on meta meta

Comment: This could get recursive, fast. My god man, look at the box you've just opened.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Challenge successfully completed

<sub><sub><sub>[not really..but close](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/159949/144680)</sub></sub></sub>

Comment: You need a fez for the fez for the fez for the fez for the fez for the babushka

Comment: And you, sir, are the winner.

Answer (score 14):

1st rule of meta.meta **never ask about meta.meta**.

Nope doesn't exist.

Not possible to get the hat here.

---

It is kind of like trying to get the [Precognitive](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/131/precognitive) badge on any of the trilogy sites.

Comment: In this case meta is meta.meta.

Answer (score 7):

Poking through the hat closet of the [top hat owners on MSO](http://winterba.sh/leaderboard/meta.stackoverflow.com), I can't find anyone with that hat so I presume it's just not possible.

This is much like the situation with the [Convention badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/901/convention) which you cannot get on meta.

Answer (score 6):

Alas, MSO is the only place one cannot earn the Constantinopolitan hat. It's because of the Very Special Relationship that MSO has to both Stack Overflow and the network at large. We apologize for the inconvenience, but I'm sure you'll be able to unlock many of the others!

Comment: Challenge accepted.

Comment: @TinyTimPost come at me bro

Comment: [Someone beat me to it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159949/winterbash-is-hackable-trickable)

Answer (score 3):

If meta.meta existed you would then want the Constantinopolitan hat for meta.meta and therefore need meta.meta.meta, what is the stopping condition...

Damn it, stackoverflow!

Comment: There's a pretty easy solution to this--recursion.

Answer (score 2):

I feel compelled to link [What about meta-meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/55/169404).

In my opinion, this is **voodoo**.