# Winterbash is hackable / trickable

Tags: bug, status-completed, winter-bash-2012, hacked

I want to report that it is fairly simple to hack (*just trick really*) the system, and assign any hat to my avatar.

I cannot ***earn*** any hat, but I can wear one as if I had earned it.

It happens because there is no check made on the back-end if I have actually earned the hat yet. If I pass the right ID I wear it.

[image: Wearing a hat I do not own]

---

This is not a manipulation of the sprite's CSS for my own viewing. The hat is really assigned, and I wear it everywhere.

Comment: Just make sure you keep the uniform on when you're delivering Captain Hook Fish and Chips dinners to those guys at IBM.

Comment: Now everyone is going to have beards!

Comment: Maybe you could sell the hats (and beard) on Ebay.

Comment: just unlocked inception mode... *Constantinopolitan* on meta ;)

Comment: Heh funny, I actually though about this yesterday but then was like "no, they would surely have a check so I won't even try that..."

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Well, the check was there … in a way. Your pirate hat never made it into the database.

Unfortunately, *caching* of the fact that you're now wearing the hat was made *outside* of this check, and since this value is retrieved from cache most of the time, in the vast majority of cases you would indeed seem to be wearing it.

Needless to say that this is fixed now (and the "who is wearing what" cache was cleared).

Order in hat land is restored. Thanks for letting us know.

[image: cat with a top hat]

Comment: You did it faster before I capture my photos with all hats :(

Comment: @balpha, unfortunately it is not.. the issue still persists (*as you can see, i just re-did the trick*).. The problem is that if i change the hat id before clicking on it, it gets assigned as if i owned the hat..

Comment: @Gaby You're wearing the Copacabana to me (look at your profile in incognito/private mode, or wait five minutes until your in-browser cache is refreshed). When switching hats, the server doesn't confirm to your browser whether you actually own the hat, so you yourself may see the wrong hat. We don't care about people cheating themselves. That's no different from using the inspector to change your reputation.

Comment: @balpha, aha moment ... thanks for clearing that up :) +1 and accept

Comment: Awwww they took my hat away. :'(

Answer (score 12):

+1 for unlocking inception mode, however to see if a user has *really been awarded a hat* you can check the hat link on their profile. It won't show up if they were't awarded the hat...

Comment: trololol, 0x7cf7fb5a